# Card not clickable in a Stack

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am following https://github.com/devefy/Flutter-Story-App-UI to build some UI components but I can't seem to make the cards clickable.

The PageView builder is supposed to manipulate the currentPage value to change the page, but the PageView builder is on top of the stack and blocks all GestureDetectors under it.

I can't think of any solutions atm, any help is appreciated.

```
PageController cardController =
        PageController(initialPage: images.length - 1);

cardController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        currentPage = cardController.page;
      });
    });

Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
          StackedCards(currentPage,postList),
          Positioned.fill(
              child: PageView.builder(
                         itemCount: images.length,
                         controller: cardController,
                         reverse: true,
                         itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                         return Container();
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
```

Comment: What are you trying to build?

Comment: i want to achieve this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/devefy/Flutter-Story-App-UI/master/assets/preview.png  but want to make the tiles clickable

Answer (score 0):

Some clickable widgets : `GestureDetector, InkWell, InkResponse`

```
  GestureDetector(
      onTap: ...,
      child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
              StackedCards(currentPage,postList),
              Positioned.fill(
                  child: PageView.builder(
                             itemCount: images.length,
                             controller: cardController,
                             reverse: true,
                             itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                             return Container();
                          },
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ));
```

Comment: that makes the entire widget clickable, i just want the tiles to be clickable as they are going to link to other pages